# Sprite not shown

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to show a sprite.

HTML file :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/releases/download/v2.7.5/phaser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

`main.js` :

```
(() => {
    var preload = () => {
        Game.load.image("player", "assets/player.png");
    },

    create = () => {
        Game.add.sprite(225, 450, "player");
    },

    update = () => {

    },

    Game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, "game",
        {
            preload : "preload",
            create : "create",
            update : "update"
        }
    );
})();
```

The sprite is just not shown, there is just a full black background.
Firefox developer console says `TypeError: this.onPreloadCallback.call is not a function`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are defining the `var Game` you have to point properly to the functions you have defined before.

```
(() => {
    var preload = () => {
        Game.load.image("player", "assets/player.png");
    },

    create = () => {
        Game.add.sprite(225, 450, "player");
    },

    update = () => {

    };

    var Game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, "game",
    {
        preload : preload,
        create : create,
        update : update
    });
})();
```

is equivalent to:

```
(() => {
    var Game = new Phaser.Game(500, 500, Phaser.AUTO, "game",
    {
        preload : () => {
            Game.load.image("player", "assets/player.png");
        },
        create : () => {
            Game.add.sprite(225, 450, "player");
        },
        update : () => {}
    });
})();
```

Comment: It was pretty obvious after all. Thanks.